# Checking for data if an array has data present

Tags: php, arrays

I am wanting to check if there is data present in an array of data so that I can preform a function.  Would I just use `in_array`?

**Array:**

```
["OpenHomes"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Start"]=>
    string(21) "/Date(1354323600000)/"
    ["End"]=>
    string(21) "/Date(1354326300000)/"
  }
```

Would I just do the following?

```
if(in_array($detail['OpenHomes']))
{
    echo 'yes';
}else{
    echo 'no';
}
```

I am wanting to check if there is anything present within `OpenHomes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if(!empty($detail) && in_array('OpenHomes',$detail))
{
    echo 'yes';
}else{
      echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check by

```
 if ($detail['OpenHomes']) {
```

or

```
  if (count($detail['OpenHomes']) > 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
count($detail['OpenHomes'])
```

or

```
sizeof($detail['OpenHomes']) // its alias, same function with different name
```

to get count of elements in that array, but that will count empty elements too.

Answer (score 1):

Or this

```
if( !empty($details['openHomes']) )
{
  //
}
else
{
  //
}
```